# Django PostgreSQL double index cleanup

Tags: django, postgresql, indexing

We've got this table in  our database with 80GB of data and 230GB of Indexes. We are constrained on our disk which is already maxed out.

What bothers me is we have two indexes that look pretty darn similar

```
 CREATE        INDEX tracks_trackpoint_id   ON tracks_trackpoint USING btree (id)   
 CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tracks_trackpoint_pkey ON tracks_trackpoint USING btree (id)
```

I have no idea what's the history behind this, but the first one seems quite redundant. What could be the risk of dropping it ? This would buy us one year of storage.

Comment: I understand the second index might have been created automatically because of a ManyToMany relation with another model, but would that model still be happy with the pkey index ?, performance-wise ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drop the first index, it is totally redundant.

If your tables are 80GB and your indexes 230GB, I am ready to bet that you have too many indexes in your database.

[Drop the indexes that are not used.](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/get-rid-of-your-unused-indexes/)

Comment: Thank you, you're raising my confidence further, and I actually remember reading your article a while ago and dropping on big index already.

Comment: the index is not UNUSED according to the query in your article.It just seems quite redundant.

Comment: We have a third index on timestamps, which makes sense if you need all trackpoints in a short interval. That one is.a further 42GB. and one on trackid and timestamp, and that's another 41GB. One more on track id alone, 37GB. That one might be redundant with the former, once you've got the +- 2k points in a tracklog, getting this in.a period is orders of magnitude easier

Comment: well, for that one I should think the other way around, the one on trackid and timestamp actually can return all records with a particular trackid.

Answer (score 0):

Careful as I am, I disabled the index to benchmark this, and the query seems to fallback nicely on the other index. I'll try a few variants.

```
appdb=# EXPLAIN analyze SELECT * FROM tracks_trackpoint where id=266082;
 Index Scan using tracks_trackpoint_id on tracks_trackpoint  (cost=0.57..8.59 rows=1 width=48) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=0 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (id = 266082)
 Total runtime: 0.040 ms
(3 rows)

appdb=# UPDATE pg_index SET indisvalid = FALSE WHERE indexrelid = 'tracks_trackpoint_id'::regclass;

appdb=# EXPLAIN analyze SELECT * FROM tracks_trackpoint where id=266082;
 Index Scan using tracks_trackpoint_pkey on tracks_trackpoint  (cost=0.57..8.59 rows=1 width=48) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=0 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (id = 266082)
 Total runtime: 0.036 ms
(3 rows)
```

Comment: I just killed the index and everything is running fine